# "Increment" a string of uppercase characters

Tags: python, python-2.x

Given a string of uppercase characters, return a string corresponding to the next item in the following series:

```
A, B, ..., Z, AA, AB, ..., AZ, BA, ..., BZ, ..., ZZ, AAA, ...
```

My code:

```
def increment_char(c):
    """
    Increment an uppercase character, returning 'A' if 'Z' is given
    """
    return chr(ord(c) + 1) if c != 'Z' else 'A'


def increment_str(s):
    lpart = s.rstrip('Z')
    if not lpart:  # s contains only 'Z'
        new_s = 'A' * (len(s) + 1)
    else:
        num_replacements = len(s) - len(lpart)
        new_s = lpart[:-1] + increment_char(lpart[-1])
        new_s += 'A' * num_replacements
    return new_s
```

Proof my code works according to the specification I gave above:

```
In [4]: increment_str('A')
Out[4]: 'B'

In [5]: increment_str('Z')
Out[5]: 'AA'

In [6]: increment_str('AA')
Out[6]: 'AB'

In [7]: increment_str('AZ')
Out[7]: 'BA'

In [8]: increment_str('ZZ')
Out[8]: 'AAA'
```

One thing I would ask you ignore is whether or not you think `s` and `new_s` (but only those two) are good names for identifiers, because they are not present in the real code (only the trimmed down version for here). All other suggestions, bug reports, etc., are welcome.

Comment: How much have you trimmed from the code to post it here?

Comment: In the real code, `increment_str` isn't dealing with strings like 'AA', 'AB', etc. It's dealing with longer strings and parsing that bit out. I have removed all the code dealing with the rest of that string and presented a simpler function. The code is exact except for the two changes I mentioned in the post, just out of context. This is also why `increment_str` doesn't have a docstring here.

Comment: This looks like base 26. How about going from "base 26 " to int, increment, and go back?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The more the code, the more real and helpful the review can be. 100s of lines are welcome if properly explained.

Comment: @Caridorc I've never worked in base 26, though I do notice the similarity to the way positional numbering works. However, I don't think Python's built-in `int` function uses 'A-Z' as the base 26 "digits". `int('Z', 26)` raises a `ValueError` for me in Python 2.7.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Indeed, the functions should be written by hand in this case and may turn out more complex than your code. But maybe they will turn out simpler, worth trying

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Or maybe you could replace A-tenth-letter with 1-10 and shift the other letters 10 positions down to use built-ins. Nothing is tested, just thinking out loud.

Comment: `returning 'A' if 'Z' is given` that should be a doctest

Comment: @Caridorc It's not quite base 26, since there is no letter that corresponds to 0.

Comment: @200_success A = 0 and base 25

Comment: @Caridorc It's not base 25 either, since there are 26 symbols.

Answer (score 3):

A slight simplification of the `if else` structure is possible:

```
def increment_str(s):
    lpart = s.rstrip('Z')
    num_replacements = len(s) - len(lpart)
    new_s = lpart[:-1] + increment_char(lpart[-1]) if lpart else 'A'
    new_s += 'A' * num_replacements
    return new_s
```